# MQ Administration - Organizational Positioning

Tags: ibm-mq

This is a discussion point I'd like to raise, regarding how folks position the administration of MQ.  Is it seen as a resource/utility function, like networks, databases, or servers, or is it rather identified as being closely linked to applications, and therefore, integrated closely in application development/sustainment?  Or rather, might it only be kept separate from applications, if there is enough demand for MQ admin activities in multiple projects/applications, so as to not be too aligned with anyone application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen it both ways. 
The larger the organization, the demand for MQ services will be high  and hence a separate team of MQ admins. They maintain the MQ network as well as work on various projects that involve MQ.
In small companies MQ is aligned with either infrastructure administration team or application support team especially the middleware support team.

Comment: This is indeed what I came to realize in my review of our organization.  We have both types at the Defense Logistics Agency. Mine is characterized as the former mostly... the folks we work with at other field sites are more akin to the latter...

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, MQ looks like a platform which integrate services and applications. It works like a factory that package the message, store them in a queue system and send them out to the services and applications, instead of connecting and directly exchanging information with each other.

Comment: thanks ... actually i have a handle on the use of MQ .. it's just the way other sites actually organize the administrators that i'm wondering about...